# lcc tmpnam crash

Tags: c

When I use the `lcc` compiler and call `tmpnam(buf)` then the program crashes.

```
Reason: L_tmpnam indicates that buf must be 14 bytes long, while the string returned 
is "D:\Documents and settings\Paul\Temporary\TmP9.tmp" which is much longer than 14.
```

What do I wrong, how can this behavior be explained.

Comment: Please Show some code...

Answer (score 0):

Verbatim from `man tmpnam`:

> Never use this function.  Use mkstemp(3) or tmpfile(3) instead.

---

Anyway, as you asked for it:

The name generated by `tmpnam()` consists of a file name of maximum `L_tmpnam` lenght **prefixed** with a directory of name `P_tmpdir`.

So the buffer to by passed to `tmpnam()` is best declared (if C99):

```
char pathname[strlen(P_tmpdir) + 1 + L_tmpnam + 1] = ""; /* +1 for dir delimiting `/` and +1 for zero-termination */
```

If non C99 you might go for this:

```
size_t sizeTmpName = strlen(P_tmpdir) + 1 + L_tmpnam + 1;
char * pathname = calloc(sizeTmpName, sizeof (*pathname));
if (NULL == pathname)
  perror("calloc() for 'pathname'");
```

Then call `tmpnam()` like this:

```
if (NULL == tmpnam(pathname))
  fprintf(stderr, "tmpnam(): a unique name cannot be generated.\n");
else
  printf("unique name: %s\n", pathname);

... /* do soemthing */

/* if on non C99 and calloc(() was called: */
free(pathname);
```

Comment: So the buf requires a length L_tmpdir + L_tmpnam. Thanks for your answer, I will try it.

Comment: @PaulVerbelen: To not forget to **add one more** character for the "strings" zero-termination! (see my example)

Comment: @PaulVerbelen: I was wrong with the prefix. Please see my corrected answer.